# How to get the selectionchange event in Qt

Tags: qt, qt4, symbian, nokia

I have a class inherited from `QWidget`, now in that class I will be creating a`QListView` object and filling up the items to view.
When the selection of items in the list view gets changed, I want to get the `selectionChange` event.

How can I achieve this?. Please tell me in brief.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you have a view, you will have a model that will be used to select item. It's called a `QItemSelectionModel`.

For example, with your `QListView`, you can get the selectionModel this way :

```
QItemSelectionModel* selectionModel() const;
```

Now, from that model, you'll be able to connect on many signals :

```
void currentChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous )
void currentColumnChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex & previous )
void currentRowChanged ( const QModelIndex & current, const QModelIndex &    previous )
void selectionChanged ( const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected )
```

I think it will help you a bit!

Comment: andy.. it got worked.. thaks lot.. but i am in trouble with some other problem i.e,  if i do keypress on listviewitem keypress event is not coming.even though i have overrden the "keyPressEvent"methods still i am not getting event.. how to install the keypress event to listview? 
Thanks

Comment: That's the problem with event I guess, you seem to have to use different "kind" of events... With the signals&slots, you just don't care how the selection changes, it just lets you know when it changes... Anyway, I would suggest to add an eventfilter on your listview... Have a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1785251/problem-filtering-mousepressevent-with-installeventfilter/1785307#1785307

Comment: thanks, i will look into this, if i have any problem i will get back to you, thank you.

Comment: I'm using Qt 4.8 and only selectionChanged worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html You might want to use QListWidget instead of view, I don't remember specifics why, but this class has these signals you want to use.

---

https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qlistwidget.html#itemSelectionChanged
This is the signal you have to connect to.

Make a slot in your class declaration:

```
 private slots:
     void selChanged();
```

Fill this slot with what you want to do upon selection change.
Connect the signal to this slot somewhere in your class - perhaps in the constructor of your QWidget derivative.

```
 connect(yourListWidget, SIGNAL(itemSelectionChanged()), this, SLOT(selChanged()));
```

that's it

Comment: i tried the way you suggested its not coming.. connect is returning false and one more thing,Qt doc says selectionchaged is a virtual slot, i tried by overriding the slot.. still its not coming..
i don't no what is wrong. can you pls help